# GET is always returning 0 id value. Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

thanks for your soon answer

Currently I got back in this project and I don´t know the reason why i´m always getting 0 in the GET request. I attach all the evidence.

I´m getting zero in the PK ID value. But that´s incorrect. When I do the query in the database I get all the correct pk values in order.

I choose IDENTITY in PK´s to achieve auto-incremental keys, and at the same time respect the order in the database and do not contaminate the keys. I already know that I could select sequence, and also made the sequence in my db.

### Spring boot, spring data jpa, postgreSQL

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name = "CATALOGS")
public class Catalogs implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) // usar identity para llave autoincr
    @Column(name = "CAT_ID")
    private int id;

    @NotEmpty(message = "CarName must not be empty")
    @Column(name = "CAT_CAR_NAME")
    private String carName;

    @NotEmpty(message = "CarModel must not be empty")
    @Column(name = "CAT_CAR_MODEL")
    private String carModel;

    @NotEmpty(message = "CarYear must not be empty")
    @Column(name = "CAT_CAR_YEAR")
    private int carYear;

    @NotEmpty(message = "CarVersion must not be empty")
    @Column(name = "CAT_CAR_VERSION")
    private String carVersion;

    @NotEmpty(message = "CarPrice must not be empty")
    @Column(name = "CAT_CAR_PRICE")
    private int carPrice;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Items.class, mappedBy = "itemId", orphanRemoval = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Items> catItem;

}
```

```
@Repository("catalogsRepository")
@Transactional
public interface CatalogsRepository extends CrudRepository<Catalogs, Integer> {

    List<Catalogs> findAll();

    // I can use Repository interface to return Optional
    Optional<Catalogs> findById(Integer id);


}
```

```
@Service("serviceCatalogs")
public class ServiceCatalogsImpl implements ServiceCatalogs {

    public static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ServiceCatalogsImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("catalogsRepository")
    private CatalogsRepository catsRepo;

    @Override
    public List<CatalogsModel> findAllCatalogs() {
      //CatalogsModel is a BusinessObject to return and avoid to return the DTO directly

        List<Catalogs> catRep = catsRepo.findAll();
        List<CatalogsModel> lsResp = null;

        if (!catRep.isEmpty()) {

            CatalogsModel target = new CatalogsModel();
            lsResp = new ArrayList<>();

            for (Catalogs catSource : catRep) {
                target.setCarModel(catSource.getCarModel());
                target.setCarName(catSource.getCarName());
                target.setCarPrice(catSource.getCarPrice());
                target.setCarVersion(catSource.getCarVersion());
                target.setCarYear(catSource.getCarYear());
                lsResp.add(target);
            }

            lsResp.stream().forEach(System.out::println);

        }
        return lsResp;
    }
```

```
APP YML:

server:
    port: 9080

logging:
    level:
        org:
            springframework: ERROR
spring:
    datasource:
        password:***********
        platform: ***********
        url: 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/***********'
        username: postgres
    jpa:
        hibernate:
            ddl-auto: validate
            naming:
                physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl    
        properties:
            hibernate: {jdbc: {lob: {non_contextual_creation: true}}}
```

[image: always return zero 0 in id pk]

Comment: As recommended in a rather cryptic answer, it is always recommended to use the nullable wrapper type for the ID, since before saving the ID is "no ID". I will also note that is is generally _much_ friendlier for methods like your `findAllCatalogs()` method to [return empty lists instead of null](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern); not only does it make your method much simpler to implement, it prevents callers from having to make pointless null checks.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
private int id;
```

To

```
private Integer id;
```

Answer (score 0):

In CatalogsModel you are not setting id

Add `target.setIdCatalog(catSource.getid);`

```
for (Catalogs catSource : catRep) {
                target.setCarModel(catSource.getCarModel());
                target.setCarName(catSource.getCarName());
                target.setCarPrice(catSource.getCarPrice());
                target.setCarVersion(catSource.getCarVersion());
                target.setCarYear(catSource.getCarYear());
                target.setIdCatalog(catSource.getid);
                lsResp.add(target);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "CAT_ID")
private int id;
```